# Javascript return undefined And Object fact

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I just checked javascript functions behavior 
And i also want to know everyone to check it and  tell me the difference between those two javascript function behavior

Sample Code is As follows

```
document.write("Hello");


var one = foo1();
var two = foo2();

document.writeln(two);
document.writeln(one);


function foo2 (){
   return 
   {
            bar:"hello"
   };

}

function foo1 (){
   return {
            bar:"hello"
   };

}
```

> And OUTPUT is
>
> Hello  undefined   [object Object]

I just want to know How ??

Comment: Automatic semicolon insertion (ASI) tricks you in the first snippet. It inserts a semicolon immediately after `return` keyword, just before the line-break.

Comment: foo2 has a line break so it returns undefined.

Comment: What do you to do ? foo1 return an object, if you want content use {one} or JSON.stringify(one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JavaScript specification describes a feature called Automatic Semicolon Insertion. Read more about this [here](https://codeburst.io/ecmascript-automatic-semicolon-insertion-50f09091e377)

```js
document.write("Hello");


var one = foo1();
var two = foo2();

document.writeln(JSON.stringify(one));
document.write(JSON.stringify(two));


function foo2 (){
   return {
            bar:"hello"
   };

}

function foo1 (){
   return {
            bar:"hello"
   };

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following does not work as you expect:

```
function foo2 (){
   return 
   {
            bar:"hello"
   };

}
```

the return statement is executed, and then `{ bar:"hello" };` is just a code block; an unreachable one, because it comes right after the return statement is evaluated.
To fix it, make sure the return statement is on the same line as the object's opening curly bracket:

```
function foo2 (){
   return {
            bar:"hello"
   };

}
```

Now for the printing part - `document.writeln()` accepts calls `.toString()` on its argument, which for objects means printing `[object object]`.
run `JSON.stringify()` on the objects before printing them, like so:

```
function toJSON(arg) {
    return JSON.stringify(arg, null, 2)
}

document.writeln(toJSON(two));
document.writeln(toJSON(one));
```

- Note that I've used `JSON.stringify(arg, null, 2)` instead of just `JSON.stringify(arg)`, because the `2` argument indicates spacing, causing it to be pretty-printed and more human readable.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you dont need `;` to end a line of code so `foo2()` returns with no value(undefined) when it reaches the return statement, that is why you see undefined, and parses the rest like a block of code, but never reaches it. The second function does what you expect it to and returns the object. If you write `document.writeln(one.bar);` you should see `Hello`.

Answer (score 0):

The `body` of the `return` statement has to stay on the same line.

You get `undefined` in `foo1()` because you don't return nothing, that's because of ASI.

```
return // this returns undefined
{
    "foo": "bar"
}
```

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return#Automatic_Semicolon_Insertion

Answer (score 0):

Ahah! This is one of Javascript problem (or trick?)

As you might noticed, you don't always have to insert the final semicolon at the end of your instructions.
For exemple,

```
let x = '3'
```

is the same as
    let x = '3';
Actually, the browser will always reads it like the second line. This is due to the ASI (Auto Semicolon Insertion) that tries to insert semicolon in an intelligent way.

But the problem is that we do not see the real action of ASI, making it harder to debug.

Here's how the first function is transformed :

```
function foo1 (){
   return {
            bar:"hello"
   };
}
```

And here's how the second function is transformed :

```
function foo2 (){
   return ;
   {
            bar:"hello"
   };

}
```

(Note the ";" just after the `return` )

And that's why identation is much more important than you can think!

You may want to interest you about the ASI :

- [Bradley Braithwaite's blog](http://www.bradoncode.com/blog/2015/08/26/javascript-semi-colon-insertion/)
- [inimino's blog](http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_semicolons)